# Alternative to django concrete inheritance

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm, relational-database

I have a Django model class which encompass various types of model classes like:

```
Content > (Audio, Video, Image)
```

I want to perform queries on this parent model like Content.objects.filter() or Content.objects.recent(). How do i come about this? Presently i am using django's concrete model inheritance, which I suppose impose lot of overheard on the db performance by using joins for the parent classes. I cannot use abstract class because that would not permit me to perform queries on the parent class. Here are my models definitions:

```
class BaseContent(models.Model):
"""
    Concrete base model to encompass all the local and social content.
    We need a single queryset for all the content on the app.
"""
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=255, default='')
    description = models.TextField(_('description'), default='', blank=True)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    allow_comments = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    created = AutoCreatedField(_('created'))

    objects = BaseContentManager()


class Video(BaseContent):
    ACTIVITY_ACTION = 'posted a video'

    UPLOAD_TO = 'video_files/%Y/%m/%d'
    PREVIEW_UPLOAD_TO = 'video_frames/%Y/%m/%d'

    video_file = models.FileField(_('video file'), upload_to=UPLOAD_TO)
    preview_frame = models.ImageField(
        _('Preview image'), upload_to=PREVIEW_UPLOAD_TO, blank=True,
        null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(VideoCategory, blank=True, null=True)
    num_plays = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    num_downloads = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar scenario which i have solved using an external named Django Polymorphic, the library seemed to work seamlessly. A few major projects use Django Polymorphic including Django-shop.

Link:
https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic

Don't quote me on this but i've read a few sources in the past that have mentioned that django_polymorphic models does not have the same performance issues caused by the standard Django ORM concrete inheritance implementation.